# Adjust Prestashop theme to autoresize

Tags: prestashop

I'm using Prestashop for a a project but it doesn't display correctly in the mobile version. I managed to find out that it's to do wth the grid system and I think I can amend the global CSS file to include the stack overflow?

As far as I can tell it's a set size.

I don't know any coding so if you could help me that would be much appreciated.

```
/* columns */
#columns {
  overflow: hidden;
  background: url(../img/black/columnsBg.jpg) repeat-x;
  padding: 0 0 10px 0;
  text-align:center;
}
.columnsInner {
  width: 980px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align:left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you use the prestashop default theme means its not responsive. so you can try prestashop mobile theme.

go to "Preferences > Themes"

under this you will have a option called "Enable the mobile theme."

you can enable your options there.

try this and let me know.